# Security reason for updateEmail to send an email to the original address

Tags: firebase, email, security, authentication

I came across the use case of a user changing his email. There's the `updateEmail` method, which states in the doc that a Email is being sent to the original email address which offers the opportunity to revoke the address. So the Email is being sent always to the first email ever used.

I don't quite understand the logic behind it, since someone most of the time changes his email address, he's probably doing it out of the reason that he's not using the old one anymore. So he might not even get noticed when this email arrives when he changes the email a second, or even third time. Or when a hacker changes the email.

When I change the email from A to B, and then from B to C, why don't they just send an email for revoking to address B?

Comment: maybe the "original email" refers to the "original" email address right before the change?

Comment: I assumed that the original email address refers to the first email ever used because that's what happens when I use it. Even after verifying the email address. So it might be a bug? Or do I have to consider something else? I'm using angularfire, maybe there's the problem, i gonna check it out.

Comment: It doesn't seem like @angular/fire is causing the problem. I set up a stackblitz project, if someone wants to test it aswell: https://stackblitz.com/edit/wr-angular-firebase-srs2